# PHP Recursive Directory-Iterator chunked

Tags: php

I have an Backup script which is call via curl by night. This script run over the whole base directory with Directory-Iterator an generate an XML-File with filename/directory and checksum. All the stuff will be generate with one simple curl request. But on an second much bigger site the script runs in an Timeout.

So my Question is how can I iterate in parts. My idea is to save the last proceed file into DB/tmpfile when the execution time reaches an specific limit. Then sends an response to say the client please send an new request and repeat it till the complete site is scanned.

All your comments are welcome.
Pascal

Comment: `Chunk` will make things complicated. How deep is the base directory. Can you share the script code ?

Comment: Why chunk make it more complicated. If you know the last file then you can continue the other files in the loop. The base directory is an CMS. So the there are many dirs and files. Source https://pastebin.com/WyL8BECX

Comment: Share your code on StackOverflow itself. Chunk will prove to be tedious because you will have to store and retrieve, and the same has to be done on the client side who is making those curl requests. Also, when you say chunk, you can divide the output into small outputs, but they all still run in a single request. You can use `cron` but it still isn't the best way I feel.